# How I can change 01 and 25 in 001 and 025 without change 125 in 0125?

Tags: linux, numeric-data

I have a file like this

```
Thomas_4567_01
Luc_2344_125
Ann_5780_25
```

I would like an outpu like this

```
Thomas_4567_001
Luc_2344_125
Ann_5780_025
```

How I can change 01 and 25 in 001 and 025 without change 125 in 0125?

Comment: `mv Thomas_4567_01 Luc_2344_125 Ann_5780_25 Thomas_4567_001 Luc_2344_125 Ann_5780_025`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I can't do this because this informations are into a file and I can't do this manually. I-ve report only an example but the file is too bigger

Comment: are those records one by line? is it always _ the delimiter? And is it the number in question always on the end? Also do you have there only 1 to 3 digits?

Comment: @RomeoNinov yes at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$ awk -F_ '{$NF = sprintf ("%03d", $NF)} 1' OFS=_ file
Thomas_4567_001
Luc_2344_125
Ann_5780_025
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use program like this to do the work:

```
awk -F_ '{printf "%s_%s_%03d\n", $1,$2,$3}' input_file
```